# oracle itertaion

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table named COURSE another table STUDENT.

```
COURSE_ID COURSE_NAME STUDENT_ID
  1          HISTORY    11
  2          BIOLOGY    11
  3          BOTNY      11

STUDENT_ID STUDENT_NAME
    11        AAA
    22        BBB
    33        CCC
```

Now i have to write a SQL query which returns result as below,

```
STUDENT_ID COURSE_NAME_1 COURSE_NAME_2 COURSE_NAME_3
   11        HISTORY         BIOLOGY     BOTNY
```

Help me how to write a oracle sql query for this.how do i iterate the course name for the corresponding students.

Comment: Are you writing this in Oracle or MySQL?  These are two different databases (albeit provided by the same company).

Comment: I fixed the tags.  You should fix the title.

Comment: Why do you mention the STUDENT table? It doesn't seem relevant to your question.

Comment: my question is pretty clear. I have 2 tables COURSE and STUDENT and the result in the mentioned format.

Comment: SELECT STUDENT_ID, COURSE_NAME_1, COURSE_NAME_2, COURSE_NAME_3 
FROM
(SELECT S.STUDENT_ID, C.COURSE_NAME,
RANK() over (PARTITION by C.STUDENT_ID ORDER BY C.COURSE_ID) as RNK
FROM COURSE C 
JOIN STUDENT S ON (C.STUDENT_ID = C.STUDENT_ID)
WHERE S.STUDENT_ID = 11)
PIVOT
(MAX(COURSE_NAME)
 FOR RNK IN (1 As COURSE_NAME_1, 2 As COURSE_NAME_2, 3 As COURSE_NAME_3)
);

Comment: I'm new to stack format, it looks like your question was put on hold so I can no longer answer it.  I would start by writing your query to produce the results, and then writing the PIVOT solution from there.

Comment: p.s WhiteViking is correct, the student table is not necessary in this particular example.  I used it anyway, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pivot query, but you want the courses enumerated.  You can use `row_number()` to enumerate the values and then conditional aggregation to put the values in separate columns:

```
select student_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then course_name end) as course_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then course_name end) as course_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then course_name end) as course_3
from (select c.*, row_number() over (partition by student_id order by course_id) as seqnum
      from course c
     ) c
group by student_id;
```

Comment: can you explain the working of this query?

Comment: You mentioned it is a pivot query, an example using PIVOT might also be of benefit, I copied one into the comments above.